# Can I Check Username and Password in Sql table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, passwords

I have a database table which contains usernames and passwords. My question is that Can I use if statements and return true or false depend on given username and password is true. I used to check it in c# side but I dont want to get data from database anymore.
Thanks for your replies.

Comment: I don't understand the question. MySQL only has `IF` statements in stored procedures, you can't use it in ordinary queries. And if you don't want to get the data from the database, why are you asking about MySQL?

Comment: You shouldn't store plaintext passwords in the database, you should hash them in the client application.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN EXISTS
        (SELECT  ac.id
         FROM account as ac
         WHERE ac.usernames='usernames' and ac.passwords='COMPLETED')
             THEN 1
         ELSE 0
        END
FROM account
```